# CSS Image percentage height /width based within absolute parent

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="item active">
    <!-- Slide 0 -->
    <div class="fill blur-me" >
        <div class="non-blur">
           <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/test/20151015_124614.jpg" />     
        </div> 
    </div>            
</div>
```

The **.fill** class is 100% height and width of parent.

The **.non-blur** class is absolutely positioned with a top padding of 80px; and a width of 100% and height of 100%;

I need the image to display 100% height of its parent and auto width whilst being centered - but i'm struggling to make this happen -

I have the following css for the img tag -

```
 img{
      width:auto;
      height:100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin:0 auto;
 }
```

ALl i get is a centred image at original image height..  can anyone suggest where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best cross browser way to implement 100% height would be to make the element absolute positioned inside the parent.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

`transform` would make the `img` centered and top and bottom set to zero will force it to be in 100% height of it's parent.

Experimental

`height: 100%` works fine in FF but webkit browsers seem to ignore it.